# Redirect default.aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, asp.net-2.0

I have an ASP.NET project.  Currently, it starts on the Default.aspx page.  However, I’d like to change this so that it starts on a different page.  In VS2008 it is possible to specify the start page, but that doesn’t seem to affect the published product.

I’ve tried putting a `Response.Redirect` in the Page_Load of Default.aspx, but that doesn’t seem to work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at IIS settings - normally for the site you can specify the "Default content page" and the default will be to go to the specified aspx page if that page exists in the root folder of the web site (normally it is set to default.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Open your solution file in VS.net2008 .Go to Solution explorer .Here locate your .aspx page you want to make as the startup page (eg:MystartPage.aspx).
Now right click on MystartPage.aspx  --->Set as start page .

Comment: Whilst this works fine when debugging, it doesn't carry through to the published site